# Regex replace strings wrapped by percentages % in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User based string template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995034/user-based-string-template)

I have a string of the form `Your invoice ref %name% is overdue by %age% days` which I would like to replace with encapsulated between '%' characters with data from an object at runtime.

I have the code below, but so far I can only get it working with brackets (I cant workout the correct regex for percentages), how can I make it work for %shortcode% please?

Secondly, I also have to go about trimming left and right. Is it possible to simply return the string inside without the percentages?

```
public void GenerateReminderContent(string text, Invoice invoice)
{
    var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\([^\]]*)\]", delegate(Match match)
    {
        var shortcode = match.Value.ToLower();
        shortcode = shortcode.TrimEnd(']');
        shortcode = shortcode.TrimStart('[');

        if (shortcode == "name")
            return invoice.Name;
        else if (shortcode == "age")
            return invoice.Age;
        else
            return "unknown-shortcode";
     });
}
```

Comment: This might seem like a stupid question but cant you use string placeholders i.e. String.Format("Your invoice {0} is overdue by {1} days", invoice.Name, invoice.Age);